# iOS 9+ Universal Links don't work from Google apps

Tags: ios, google-apps, ios-universal-links

The company I work for told me to ask the following:

When a universal link is tapped in other apps (native Apple apps, Slack, etc.) our app is opened, but if the same link is tapped in any Google app (Hangouts, Inbox, etc.) the universal link is not opened directly by our app.

We set the Google app to not open links inside it and we don't have Chrome installed on devices where the app was tested.

Does anyone have the same problem? Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is the expected behavior. Universal Links do not work directly from within most Google apps — you need to have the link open a web page containing a button or other link within. That button or link can be a Universal Link, which then opens the app.

[Here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links) is more information about where Universal Links currently work and do not work.

Comment: Strangely there is very little written elsewhere about this. Thank you for your response and the link. :-)

Comment: I agree. It always surprises me that the brokenness of Universal Links doesn't get more attention...

Comment: @VanderleiMartinelli did you come up with something? ATM when I open gmail from safari to add a new user, it links straight to my app as expected. But when I do this from any google app it just opens up a blank page. Strangely this also happens when I'm adding a gmail user directly from the iPhone mail settings (only a blank page appears, no universal link redirect)?!